# What is the origin of cleating in coal?

Tags: coal

Why do some coals show cleating and some not? Is cleating in coal related to coal's plant source or depositional process or post depositional processes?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, its not well studied. It is most likely a diagenic process just because that is the source of most fractures in rock.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0166516297000128

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1674775514000341